# The phonological rules of metathesis and epenthesis

Tags: phonology, phonetics

Could you provide me with the general rule of both metathesis and epenthesis? I can write the rules regarding specific case in metathesis and epenthesis but I couldn't find out the general rule.

Comment: There are only specific rules. What do you even mean by "the general rule"?

Comment: IIRC, **SPE** gives a formulation for metathesis, in just a brief note saying that transformational notation is required for this.  (It's not very interesting.)

Comment: Would you say you can formulate a rule for the fact that there is Greek morf-e and Latin form-a?

Comment: Are you asking about English? Or are you looking for some "universal" rules?

Answer (score 2):

The 'general rule' might be that certain phonemes are difficult to say in sequence, so one either swaps them (metathesis) or inserts another (typically a vowel, epenthesis).

Comment: Or you could change one of the phonemes to a different phoneme; or you could delete one of the phonemes. There is a difference between a rule that performs a specific action, and the *reason* for there being such a rule.